# Are filters called after dispatcher forward?

Tags: liferay, servlet-filters

I have two filters in my project.
In my second filter i am using dispatcher.forward to forward that request.
Both have /* url pattern.

So my question is that after forwarding that request to /web/* url pattern from my second filter, does first filter will be called again or not.

I want my all filters to be executed after forwarding that request!